# QProcess exits the application after calling QProcess.start()

Tags: qt, qprocess, qtcore

I am using `QProcess` to run other programs. But when I exit my app after calling `QProcess.start()` it says in debug console:

```
QProcess: Destroyed while process is still running.
```

and the process closes.

But I want to keep this process running after closing my app. How I start new process:

```
QProcess p;
p.start("ssu.exe", QStringList() << "-instantinstall");
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `QProcess::startDetached`. See the docs:

> If the calling process exits, the detached process will continue to live.